# use self in class method

Tags: objective-c, ios, class

I have a class method where I want to perform this piece of code below. the problem is that in a class method you can't use something like self.view. so I'm a bit stuck here. I've found some stuff about using [self class] but I don't really understand how to use that in my piece of code.

```
for (UIView *view in [self.view subviews]) 
    {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[Circle class]]) {

            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear animations:^{
                view.alpha = 0;
                view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2-35, self.view.frame.size.height/2-35, 70, 70);
            } completion:nil];

            [view performSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.4];
        } else {
            //
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE with more info**

I have a Circle class.
in that class I have this method

```
- (IBAction)playerTap:(id)sender {


    NSString *numberString;
    numberString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",indexNumber+1];

    if (indexNumber < 14)
    {


    if ([label.text isEqualToString:numberString]) 
    {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{


        self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.2, 1.2);

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

       [UIView animateWithDuration:0.05 animations:^{
           self.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
           self.alpha = 0.2;

       } completion:nil];

    }];

    ++indexNumber;
    } 
    } else {

        self.alpha = 0.2;

        [NUMViewController gameHasEnded];

    }

}
```

when the indexNumber (a static variable) has reached a certain amount I want a method in my NUMViewController Class to be performed. I.E. the "gameHasEnded" method.

that would be a method with the code at the beginning of this post. it will remove all other circle instances from the view.

a class method seemed the most logical for me because I'm not performing the method on the circle object but it affects all the objects in my other class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not meaningful to have a class method that calls `self.view`. The class does not have a `view`, and there is no way to know which instance you mean. Why are you doing this in a class method? Move it to a the instance. If you have a shared singleton instance, than class methods can refer to it, but this is generally a bad idea and should be avoided if possible (since it ties your class to the singleton).

Comment: yes I understand. I've added some more info about my intentions. but I'm not sure how I should do it with an instance method. I keep getting unrecognized selector errors.

Comment: You should move `indexNumber` into a model class (likely a singleton object), probably something like `Game`. When the index hits 0, the `Game` would post a notification like `GameEndedNotification`. The view controller would observe that and get rid of its views. The key here is to separate Model, View, and Controller classes. But there's no reason here for class methods or static variables.

Comment: ok thanks. I'll give this a try. this whole MVC thing is still somewhat vague for me to grasp properly.